# F# round up to a specific number of decimal places

Tags: f#, rounding

for example I can use `System.Math.Round((float),2)`to round my float to the nearest 2 decimal places, but is there anyway in F# that i can ***round up*** my float to 2 decimal places? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hackish solution to rounding up

```
let round x d =
    let rounded = Math.Round(x,d)
    if rounded < x then x + Math.Pow(10,-d) else rounded
```

Comment: Ergh, an if branch just for rounding? Add half the required precision and then round, surely!

Comment: I was trying `Math.Round x 3` and it was throwing an error. IDK why! But this soln solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To round up (strictly up, rather than just away from zero):

```
let roundUp x d = 
    Math.Round(x + Math.pow(10,-d)/2,d)
```

Consider rounding 0.001 to 2dp. You want this to round to 0.01:

```
0.001 + 0.01/2 = 0.006
-> 2dp: 0.01
```

This is derived from a common way to get normal rounding from truncation; to add half the needed precision and truncate. This, however suffers for negative numbers, so the delta needs to be subtracted or added depending on the sign of the original value.

Note that if you always round up then negative amounts round towards zero. In financial situations where 2dp is usually needed, that is a bad idea as a balance of 0.021 is rounded to 0.03, but a balance of -0.021 is rounded to -0.02, and it starts to matter whether you are calculating a debit or a credit. If you do it symmetrically, e.g. always away from zero, then you don't care any more.

Comment: It's even worse than that - with the default RoundToEven behaviour, some already round numbers are unstable. For instance, roundUp 1.05 2 will produce 1.06. You'll need to use MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero in your Round and ensure you're always rounding negative numbers.